# Can a RC 7.2V 1300mAh Ni-Mh Pack be replaced by 6xAA 1300mAh Ni-MH in holder?

Tags: voltage, amperage, batteries

Can a RC 7.2V 1300mAh Ni-Mh Pack be replaced by 6xAA 1300mAh Ni-MH in holder ?

Answer (score 2):

Probably.  The only thing you haven't mentioned yet is the internal impedance, or how much the voltage drops under load and then recovers when the load goes away.

I would expect that the RC pack would have lower impedance than the AA's, meaning that it's better at supporting high loads, but if the AA's work for you, then that's great!

Also, I would expect that the RC pack (at least a good one) would have its cells closely matched so that it doesn't unbalance itself as easily as a random collection of AA's would.  But if you charge the cells individually in a AA charger or use a balancer, that shouldn't be much of a problem either.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. The key to your question is 'in a holder'. That's 12 spring-loaded contacts in series. I would expect your reliability, especially if driving a high current motor, to be very poor. It only takes one contact to loosen, overheat and oxidize, and there's you fiddling with all the cells, trying to find out which is making poor contact.

Use tagged batteries, and solder them together. They are more expensive than conventional cells, but will save you hours of frustration, or failure during a critical race.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think of that.  Good point.